# Read entire ini section and put into array

Tags: arrays, vba, vbscript, ini

Ok, so I have these functions I'm tring to use via my vba code. 
It's probably the as it would have been with vbs as well.

Here's the function(s)

```
'declarations for working with Ini files
Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileSection Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetPrivateProfileSectionA" (ByVal lpAppName As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
ByVal nSize As Long, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, _
ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Long, _
ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

'// INI CONTROLLING PROCEDURES
'reads an Ini string
Public Function ReadIni(Filename As String, Section As String, Key As String) As String
Dim RetVal As String * 255, v As Long
v = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", RetVal, 255, Filename)
ReadIni = Left(RetVal, v + 0)
End Function

'reads an Ini section
Public Function ReadIniSection(Filename As String, Section As String) As String
Dim RetVal As String * 255, v As Long
v = GetPrivateProfileSection(Section, RetVal, 255, Filename)
ReadIniSection = Left(RetVal, v + 0)
End Function
```

How can I use this to create a function that basically allows me to specify only the section I want to look in, and then find each ini string within that section and put it into an array and return that Array so I can do a loop with it?

Edit: I see that ReadIniSection returns all of the keys in a huge string.
Meaning, I need to split it up.

ReadIniSection returns something that looks like this:
"Fornavn=FORNAVN[]Etternavn=ETTERNAVN" etc etc. The[] in the middle there isn't brackets, it's a square. Probably some character it doesn't recognize. So I guess I should run it through a split command that takes the value between a = and the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps - splitting on nullchar \0:

```
Private Sub ListIniSectionLines()
    Dim S As String: S = ReadIniSection("c:\windows\win.ini", "MAIL")
    Dim vLines As Variant: vLines = Split(S, Chr$(0))
    Dim vLine As Variant
    For Each vLine In vLines
       Debug.Print vLine
    Next vLine
End Sub
```